# Is my codeigniter query right?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

the "where" statement in my query is not working.

```
$this->db->select(array("pr_id","id","unit_id","item_description","quantity","unit_cost","total_cost"));
$this->db->where('id','1');
$this->db->from("tblitem");
```

The select and from statement is perfectly fine. My datatables is appearing. But it disregards the where statement. I dont know if my statement is right. please help me thanks.

Comment: no.... remove array() from select... why you used array inside select?

Comment: your query is fine ... how do you know that your statement isn't right? you should explain this a bit more... (@ash take a look here https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB_query_builder.php#L284 - you can pass an array too )

Answer (score 1):

Remove array For Select Query and remove quotes for `id(int)`

```
$this->db->select("pr_id,id,unit_id,item_description,quantity,unit_cost,total_cost");

$this->db->from('tblitem');

$this->db->where('id',1);

$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->result();
```

Comment: Can you explain **why** this solves the problem, such that others can learn from your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is correct way.

```
    $this->db->select("pr_id","id","unit_id","item_description","quantity","unit_cost","total_cost");
$this->db->where('id',1);
$this->db->from("tblitem");
```

Comment: 3 upvotes for a totally wrong answer, this site is getting weirder and weirder... https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=query%20builder#CI_DB_query_builder::select

Answer (score 0):

Remove array from select. You can just select table columns by separating them with commas.

And also replace

```
$this->db->where('id','1');
```

with

```
$this->db->where('id',1);
```

Note: Remove quotes if the `id` field is int.

May be this will help.

Comment: wrap with quotes and search in int field will work fine. No issues

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$this->db->select("pr_id,id,unit_id,item_description,quantity,unit_cost,total_cost");
$this->db->get_Where('tblitem', array('id'=>'1'));

echo $this->db->result()
```

Hope This Help

Comment: Can you explain **why** this solves the problem, such that others can learn from your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove array from select statement, such that your query looks like this:

```
$this->db->select(`pr_id`,`id`,`unit_id`,`item_description`,`quantity`,`unit_cost`,`total_cost`);
$this->db->where('id',1);
$this->db->from('tblitem');

$result=$this->db->get();
```

Then if you want to access a single row, use:

```
$row = $result->row();
```

Or if the query results in a pure array, or an empty array when no result is found, use:

```
$result->result_array().
```

Example:

```
foreach ($result->result_array() as $row)
{
        echo $row['title'];
        echo $row['name'];
        echo $row['body'];
}
```